# Is it possible to ask for android permission but not show any activity behind it?

Tags: android, permissions

I basically want just the Permission Frame to show not any background activity. So if I was on a different app and my app asks for permissions, it doesn't open my app.

Comment: You want to do something that totally against the rule. This is like manipulating the user.

Comment: That's the first thing that came to mind, it's fine I'll just open the app front page

Comment: you can ask all permission at once on the app first screen(eg. Splash screen). You can do that.